# Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not effective?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, libpng

I'm trying to compile `libpng`, which requires the `libz`. I have installed my owner `libz.so.1` at my home and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.But it does not get any result because the output of `ldd` shows that it still uses `/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1`.

And then the output of make shows like "-L/home/zlib -lz". Why?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly where you have located the library, what you have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to, and exactly how you're compiling please?

Comment: I build it with ./configure --prefix=/home/mylibs

Comment: And what is the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to?

Comment: How did you set?have you done export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH= `? what value you are getting on `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: what is the error you're getting and when are you getting it? (at compile time or run time). What was `LD_RUN_PATH` set to at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need a symbolic link from `/home/mylibs/libz.so` to `/home/mylibs/libz.so.1`.

Note that `-lz` will search for `libz.so`, but not `libz.so.1`, so the linker will keep on searching and will find such a link in `/usr/local/lib`.

Other than that, you make want to show the NEEDED entries (which record dynamic dependencies) in the header of your executable, with:

```
$ objdump -x a.out | grep NEEDED
```

to see if they are recorded with the full path, as `libz.so` or as `libz.so.1`.

Comment: thanks all of you, i used export to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my own lib path. it can not work. But if i set this param to .bash_profile , it can work well. why?